# docker-compose basic Prometheus / Grafana example with one node exporter

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, prometheus

**Question**: how to configure the Prometheus server to pull data from the node exporter?

I have successfully set up the data sources at Grafana and see the default dashboard with the following `docker-compose.yml`. The 3 services are:

- Prometheus server
- Node exporter
- Grafana

**Dockerfile**:

```
version: '2'

services:

  prometheus_srv:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus_server
    hostname: prometheus_server


  prometheus_node:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    container_name: prom_node_exporter
    hostname: prom_node_exporter
    depends_on:
      - prometheus_srv

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana_server
    hostname: grafana_server
    depends_on:
      - prometheus_srv
```

[image]

---

#### Edit:

I used something similar to what [@Daniel Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22688/daniel-lee) shared and it seems to work:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     10s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 10s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.

scrape_configs:
  # Scrape Prometheus itself
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_timeout: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  # Scrape the Node Exporter
  - job_name: 'node'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['prom_node_exporter:9100']
```

Comment: Hello, I would add you can have a look to this project on github which is quite complete https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [YAML configuration file](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/), here is an example from the [Grafana test instance of Prometheus](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/master/docker/blocks/prometheus).

The docker file:

```
FROM prom/prometheus
ADD prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
```

The YAML file:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     10s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  evaluation_interval: 10s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Load and evaluate rules in this file every 'evaluation_interval' seconds.
rule_files:
  # - "first.rules"
  # - "second.rules"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_timeout: 10s

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      #- targets: ['localhost:9090', '172.17.0.1:9091', '172.17.0.1:9100', '172.17.0.1:9150']
      - targets: ['localhost:9090', '127.0.0.1:9091', '127.0.0.1:9100', '127.0.0.1:9150']
```